# Fixed Size column in cgridview in yii

Tags: php, html, css, yii, cgridview

[image]

In here, the remarks column became as big as the data is.But if the data is big like this, i  want to show a few characters here, maybe 20 characters; so that the column wont get big like this.In other words, how to make a fixed size column that wont get bigger with the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either set a max width for all table cells:

```
.grid-view table td {
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or force break/wrap:

```
.grid-view table td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: sry a newbie question, but where to put this css code? or should i create one?